# How to print the counted numbers and converted it?

Tags: c, pic, mplab

how to make counting numbers ?
For example, I send command to HyperTerminal, then it will reply (print) counted values.

Here the first example,

send command: UI1-UI10

reply command: UI1-UI10_in_Hexadecimal:0x3FF

The above example, Ui1 until Ui10, it count, one until ten. Then, the binary will have IIIIIIIIII (10bit), but in HyperTerminal will reply 0x3FF in hexadecimal.

2nd Example,

send command: UI5-UI7

reply command: UI5-UI7_in_Hexadecimal:0x3 or 0x03

Ui5 until Ui7, it count, five until seven. Then, the binary will have III (3bit), but in HyperTerminal will reply 0x3 or 0x03 in hexadecimal.

3rd example,

send command: UI5-UI5

reply command: UI5-UI5_in_Hexadecimal:0x1

Ui5 until Ui5, it count, five only. Then, the binary will have I (1Bit), but in HyperTerminal will reply 0x1 or 0x01 in hexadecimal.

can the above example done it Bitwise function ?

here my code :

```
void decode(unsigned char* msg) {

    unsigned char* lala[50];

    if (strstr(msg, "UI1-UI10") != NULL)
    {
        sprintf(lala, "UI1-UI10_in_Hexadecimal:0x3FF");
        sendString(lala);
    }
    else if (strstr(msg, "UI5-UI7") != NULL)
    {
        sprintf(lala, "UI5-UI7_in_Hexadecimal:0x3");
        sendString(lala);
    }
    else if (strstr(msg, "UI5-UI5") != NULL)
    {
        sprintf(lala, "UI5-UI5_in_Hexadecimal:0x1");
        sendString(lala);
    }
}
```

But, from this code got problem when the send command is different.

Comment: `lala` or `lala[0]`, `lala[1]`, `lala[2]` .... ?

Comment: @itsnotmyrealname I use `lala[50]`

Comment: you are trying passing between incompatible pointer types

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [ask] page for help clarifying this question.